# Build SQLite query in Python but execute it using sqlite3 command line program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, csv, sql-injection

I have a small Python/Flask web app that returns data from a SQLite table in CSV format. I found that it's faster to use the `sqlite3` command line program to export the query results directly to a CSV file then return the CSV file than it is to read the query results into Python, write them to an in-memory file, then return the in-memory file. However, using the `sqlite3` program means I have to build the queries myself, subjecting my app to SQL injection attacks.

**Faster, but vulnerable to SQL injection attacks**

```
queries = """
.mode csv
.headers on
.output /tmp/results.csv
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE foo = '{0}';
""".format(user_input)

subprocess.check_output(
    ["sqlite3", "/path/to/mydb.sqlite"], input=bytes(queries.encode("utf-8")))

return send_file("/tmp/results.csv", mimetype="text/csv")
```

**Safe from SQL injection, but slower**

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:////path/to/mydb.sqlite")
result = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE foo = ?", (user_input,))

csvfile = io.StringIO()
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
csvwriter.writerow(result.keys())

for row in result.fetchall():
    csvwriter.writerow(row)

 return Response(csvfile.getvalue(), mimetype="text/csv")
```

Is there a way I can use a Python library (sqlalchemy, the sqlite3 module, or anything else) to build a query that is safe from SQL injection but not actually execute the query, so that I can instead execute the query via a subprocess using the `sqlite3` command line program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct SQLite-to-CSV export path (using the `sqlite3` program's `.mode csv`)  will have a speed advantage over a more circuitous SQLite-to-Python-to-CSV export path mainly in the case of selecting large amounts of data; when selecting smaller amounts of data, the speed won't differ as much.

So depending on your schema, one option would be to use Python to query the database for a set of IDs, then use `sqlite3` to select the rest of the data using the IDs. That way the Python libraries will sanitize your user input (preventing SQL injection etc.) and what you pass to the `sqlite3` program won't be user input but IDs you yourself queried.

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:////path/to/mydb.sqlite")
result = conn.execute("SELECT ID FROM mytable WHERE foo = ?", (user_input,))
ids = [row[0] for row in result.fetchall()]

queries = """
.mode csv
.headers on
.output /tmp/results.csv
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID IN ({0});
""".format(",".join([str(id) for id in ids]))

subprocess.check_output(
    ["sqlite3", "/path/to/mydb.sqlite"], input=bytes(queries.encode("utf-8")))

return send_file("/tmp/results.csv", mimetype="text/csv")
```

This approach involves 2 queries instead of 1, but the difference may be marginal if the bottleneck is selecting all the data. Profile your app to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Inside an SQL string, the only special character is the quote `'` itself. (And the character with code 0, which would end the entire query and result in a syntax error.)

To escape single quotes, double them:

```
user_input.replace("'", "''")
```